# Cocoa Touch: Adding images in for loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

this is crashing on me when I put in an array of image urls, I think its because of me creating the UIImageView and then trying to do it again with the same name!

```
- (void)cycleImages:(NSArray *)images {


int fromLeft = 5;
   for(int n = 0; n <= [images count]; n++){

   UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:n]]]]];

   myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(fromLeft, 5, 48, 48); // from left, from top, height, width

   fromLeft = fromLeft + 53;

   //add image view to view
   [self.view addSubview:myImageView];


    NSLog(@"%@", [images objectAtIndex:n]);

}
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!
Dex

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH18-SW1) instead of an index loop. Fast enumeration is simpler, clearer, and faster—whenever you don't specifically need an index for something, there is no reason not to use fast enumeration.

> ```
>    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:n]]]]];
> ```

This assumes that `[images objectAtIndex:n]` is a string. Is that what you put into the array?

Also, because you created that image view with `alloc`, you need to release it. If you're using ARC, that's done automatically, so you don't need to do anything; otherwise, you need to either send it `release` after adding it as a subview or send it `autorelease`.

> this is crashing on me …

Please be more specific. What sort of “crash” do you get, and on what line?

If you get a crash log, please edit your question to include it.